# Android Dialog fragment. Difference between dismiss and remove from FragmentManager

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-dialogfragment

I would like to understand what is the difference between calling a dismiss() and a close() method I wrote inside of a DialogFragment in Android. Basically one gives me an error and the other one doesn't and I am trying to understand why.

I have a Java code for Android that is working, but I am trying to understand what it is exactly doing.
In my main activity, I have a portion of code that loads a dialog:

```
private void pop_New_Game_Dialogue(boolean is_There_A_Cancel_Button) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment prev = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("newgamedlg");
        if (prev != null) {
            ft.remove(prev);
        }
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        Checkboxlistview new_Game_Dialogue = Checkboxlistview.new_Instance(is_There_A_Cancel_Button);
        new_Game_Dialogue.show(ft, "newgamedlg");

    }
```

Which I have more or less copied from the  [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment#Lifecycle) reference website.

In my DialogFragment class I inflate a view from an xml source, and initialize various checkboxes using a sqlLite database.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState){
        int i;
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogue, container,
                false);
      ...
```

Finally I add an OnClickListener to a button with the command close()

```
  cancel_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                close();
            }

        });
```

The close method is a single line of code that goes like this:

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
```

Everything works using it, but if I use dismiss(); instead which if I understand correctly should be the correct method to call when getting rid of a FragmentDialogue, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

I would like to understand where this error comes from and why I don't get it when I call close();

Comment: `close` is not a method of `DialogFragment`, it probably comes from some anonymous class you have created in this scope. Use `dismiss`.

Comment: You are correct. I have changed my question to reflect that.